# Is live audio on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that this question's migration to Sound Design was rejected.

- [Live rock band having issues with vocals being buried](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24661/live-rock-band-having-issues-with-vocals-being-buried)

The recent splitting out of audio from AVP has me very confused. Why is that? Is live audio explicitly off-topic here? Where *is* live audio currently on-topic?

Comment: Seems on topic to me.  I read the question as about gear choices and the production techniques to achieve the sound you are looking for.  The fact that it involves live audio shouldn't preclude it from living here.  The fact that it's live may play a role in what answers are given, but not really what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, there is a severe culture clash between the old AVP and SSD users as what we see as sound design is immensely different. I'm a old SSD user and I do NOT see live music as a sound design topic what so ever.

Answer (score 3):

I personally would like this sort of question to be **on-topic** here although I know I'm just one opinion. I would like sound.SE to be a general making-sound site, including both traditional sound design (synthesis, foley, etc) as well as "audio production" and studio contexts, just like we saw on the "audio" side of AVP.SE. Questions about mixing, speakers, and live production are all things I'd like to see here.

Comment: Well, on my web page it says sound design meta at the top of the page. Sound design even if we include both what could go for musical and film/TV sound design, it should not be for general sound questions nor live questions imho.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is all about how to create the soundscape, making sure there is space in the mix etc., I would put this at 100% on topic here with the new version of Sound Design.

It may not have quite fit the previous scope, which was creation of individual sounds, tones etc., but as Josh says, it is about the design and creation of sound.

Comment: I can't imagine why it wouldn't be on-topic. Also trying to figure out why it was locked by the community user. :/

Comment: Suggested literature: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/14687/what-makes-you-think-youre-a-sound-designer

Comment: @TimPost - Something like this happened to me on Writers. rejecting a migration locks a question even if you re-open it later. [Unable to leave a comment on a closed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128066/149375) Hope this helps.

Comment: @Stavrosound, unrelated thought, do you think the question you linked to should be on meta rather than not?

Comment: @JoshP No, please leave it be.  Wnough liberties have been taken by incoming users with tearing apart the fabric of the community.  We don't need it torn apart any further.

Comment: But that link (Stavros) is a pretty good example of what a sound designer is all about in the SSD sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that this is a perfect example of something not on topic. Live sound has zero to do with sound design. It is audio engineering or sound mixing at best. It is in no way sound design.

Perhaps a good way for us to work out if something is on topic is to ask "who would be the perfect person to answer this question?". In this case, it would be a music producer, not a sound designer.

Comment: Anyone care to add why my answer was downvoted so much?

Comment: Because the AVP folks think it's on topic and the SSD folks think it's not, and there's more of them than there are of us( I think)

Comment: Downvoting in meta means "I disagree", nothing more.

Comment: @ErikG - For a little background, I'd like to point out that a lot of AVP users, including myself, had their questions migrated here against their wishes. This is after a merge with a video site. Now the site our questions have been sent to wants to close some of them? I can understand this point of view, I just don't agree with it.

Comment: This is a very interesting point you bring up @neilfein and something I wasn't at all aware of as a SSD user. To us it's a stream of irrelevant posts being added to a forum that we once truely loved and valued. To you you've been added to a forum you didn't want to be in and now everyone wants to kick you out. Clearly there is a big problem here for everyone!

Comment: Agreed. I for one will try to step up participation in this site, to see if I can help bring these two sides closer together.

Comment: Relevant: [We need to narrow down our scope and help center guidance, your opinion is needed!](http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/q/109/7045)

Comment: @neilfein, I hadn't thought about it like that. So we now have clearly two "parts" one that feels unwanted (by the likes of me) and one that feel that the previous community has become diluted with questions that we feel does not belong in the community we joined.

Comment: @ErikG - And both communities are, I think, quite correct in feeling as they do. There's really no "right" point of view here.

Answer (score 0):

Live music and performances have nothing to do with sound design in the SSD sense at all. 
Just in the sense that post processing/mastering a song is done post-production, but it has absolutely nothing to do with sound post-production as that is the term used for all things sound in film/TV and games (location sound recording on set not included). 
It may sound similar.
It may at first look to be quite similar.
But it just isn't the same or similar at all.